# using Arrays.sort between Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE values with Comparator

Tags: java, arrays, integer, comparator

I have this Java class with int with field, and others fields not needed for this question.

```
class MyInteger {

  int integer;

  public MyInteger(int integer) {
    this.integer = integer;
  }

  public int getInteger() {
    return integer;
  }

  public void setInteger(int integer) {
    this.integer = integer;
  }

}
```

Now I test my class

First: I created the Array with integers.

```
int size = 12;
MyInteger[] integers = new MyInteger[size];
for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) {
  integers[p] = new MyInteger(
      java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
      Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}
```

Now print it.

```
System.out.println("UNSORTED");
for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) {
  int length = String.valueOf(integers[p].getInteger()).length();
  String stringValue = new String(new char[12 - length]).replace("\0", " ") + integers[p].getInteger();
  System.out.println("p:" + p + " -> " + stringValue);
}
```

Here, I'm trying to sorted it.

```
Arrays.sort(integers, new Comparator<MyInteger>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(MyInteger myInteger1, MyInteger myInteger2) {
    return myInteger2.getInteger() - myInteger1.getInteger();
  }
});
```

Print it again

```
System.out.println("DESCENDING");
for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) {
  int length = String.valueOf(integers[p].getInteger()).length();
  String stringValue = new String(new char[12 - length]).replace("\0", " ") + integers[p].getInteger();
  System.out.println("p:" + p + " -> " + stringValue);
}
```

Now my OUTPUT...

```
    UNSORTED
    p:0 ->   1516262435
    p:1 ->  -1895913122
    p:2 ->    460516193
    p:3 ->   2056891047
    p:4 ->   1556892429
    p:5 ->    609045519
    p:6 ->  -1105298052
    p:7 ->   1015464430
    p:8 ->   -232510140
    p:9 ->     28575513
    DESCENDING
    p:0 ->  -1105298052
    p:1 ->  -1895913122
    p:2 ->   2056891047
    p:3 ->   1556892429
    p:4 ->   1516262435
    p:5 ->   1015464430
    p:6 ->    609045519
    p:7 ->    460516193
    p:8 ->     28575513
    p:9 ->   -232510140
```

I know, because sometimes the capacity (in bits) of (int2 - int1) is greater of simple int
**What is my Better alternative to do that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`Integer.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) in your Comparator to achieve this:

```
Arrays.sort(integers, (i1, i2) -> Integer.compare(i2.getInteger(), i1.getInteger()));
```

Or even shorter using [`Comparator.comparingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```
Arrays.sort(integers, Comparator.comparingInt(MyInteger::getInteger).reversed());
```

The result in both cases should look like this:

```
DESCENDING
p:0 ->   2023840480
p:1 ->   1411652946
p:2 ->   1329894719
p:3 ->   1158939955
p:4 ->    652971815
p:5 ->   -118538025
p:6 ->   -157722835
p:7 ->  -1370854542
p:8 ->  -1925460195
p:9 ->  -1937778542
```

Comment: I don’t think that the actual implementation of `Integer.compare` is relevant. All that matters, is that using minus instead of a comparison is wrong whereas `Integer.compare` will do it right. There are chances that the JVM’s optimizer replaces invocations of `Integer.compare` by an intrinsic operation, but regardless of how it works, it is guaranteed not to have such overflow issues as using minus has.

Comment: @Holger Yes, that's right. It was just to show OP, that there can't be any overflow issues using `Integer.compare();`, because OP had some promlems  using that solution. I can remove that part now.